# Jquery - Animate numbers from an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My PHP script returns this JSON

```
{number: "13", data: "930", test: "3", invoice: "100"}
```

I wish these numbers to appear with an animation (go from 0 to number) in 4 different div in this way :

```
<div id="1m" class="count">13</div>
<div id="2t" class="count">930</div>
<div id="3d" class="count">3</div>
<div id="4a" class="count">100</div>
```

But I can not create a loop for each data to go to the right place automatically

Here is the beginning of my javascript, for the moment there is only `data.number` which is put in each `div`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'example.php',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: data.number
      }, {
        duration: 100,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });

  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to give each element a `data` attribute that links it to the correct property from the `data` object, you could re-use your loop.

I.e.:

```
<div id="1m" data-prop="number" class="count">
<!--           ⬆  ⬆  ⬆  ⬆  ⬆               -->
```

```js
const data = { number: "13", data: "930", test: "3", invoice: "100" };

$('.count').each(function() {
  const prop = $(this).data("prop");     //Get the element's data-prop
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
    Counter: data[prop]                  //Use that property
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1m" data-prop="number" class="count"></div>
<div id="2t" data-prop="data" class="count"></div>
<div id="3d" data-prop="test" class="count"></div>
<div id="4a" data-prop="invoice" class="count"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the values.

**With dynamic data**

```js
const data = {number: "13", data: "930", test: "3", invoice: "100"};

$.each(data, function(index, value) {

  const $this = $('<div />', {
        "class": 'count',
        text: value });

  $('#main').append($this);

    jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" />
```

**With Static data**

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  jQuery({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
      $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1m" class="count">13</div>
<div id="2t" class="count">930</div>
<div id="3d" class="count">3</div>
<div id="4a" class="count">100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this - https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js

```js
$.ajax({
      url: 'example.php',
      success: function(data) {
        let number = new CountUp('number', data.number).start();
        let data = new CountUp('data', data.data).start();
        let test = new CountUp('test', data.test).start();
        let invoice = new CountUp('invoice', data.invoice).start();
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1m" class="count" id="number">13</div>
<div id="2t" class="count" id="data">930</div>
<div id="3d" class="count" id="test">3</div>
<div id="4a" class="count" id="invoice">100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a vanilla javascript function:

- `element` is the DOM element containing your number.
- `start` is from which number the counter starts.
- `end` is from which number the counter stops.
- `delay` is the delay for the number to change. Default is 10ms.
- `step` is the number that will be added to the current number. Default is 1.

```js
animateNumber(document.querySelector('.animated'), 0, 5, 100);
animateNumber(document.querySelector('.fast-animated'), 0, 100, 10, 2);

function animateNumber(element, start, end, delay = 10, step = 1) {
  let current = start,
    interval = null;

  element.innerText = start;
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    current += step;
    element.innerText = current;
  
    if (current === end) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      
      interval = null;
    }
  }, delay);
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">0</div>
<div class="fast-animated">0</div>
```